# docker can connect to localhost of host machine, but not to a local ip of other machine in host network

Tags: docker, networking

I have 2 EC2 instances, they can talk normally through curl,
the EC2 marked dolphin has a docker container in it, and all security groups and firewall ports setup is OK.

to connect from docker into localhost of dolphin
i will use "host.docker.internal" instead of "localhost" because localhost means docker container itself.

[image]

**my question :**
how can i make docker not only talk to localhost of it's host, but to connect to the local machine of IP 172.30.2.194

--network host is not working, because i have another container linked... this is the error

> /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: Conflicting
> options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would
> result in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker containers internally use the 172.x.x.x ip range. You can't connect to the EC2 because the ip range is clashing and the network stack routes the packets among the docker network instead of the "external" VPC.

A solution would be to change the address range of the VPC which holds your EC2 machines. You could use 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x.